# Design practice for certain data sets?

Tags: python, django, database, database-design, django-models

I am trying to dig into database design of grofers.com to understand how grofers manages to list store of merchant and make available to the buyers. What i found is

For Merchant to list their store

**Basic Details**

```
Name, Email,Phone,Store Category
```

**Financial Detai**l

```
Name of legal entity,PAN number,Registered office address,City
```

**Store Detail**

```
Store Name,Location(google map),Store Address,Store Contact Number,Store Timings (  _ to _  and store off Sunday ) **// how to model such store timing**
```

**Product**

**Name of Product,Item in stock,Price,Description**

**Category**

**Name of Category( Grocery, Bakery & Sweets, Food, Meat, Sports & Fitness, etc )**

I come up with following design

```
class Store(models.Model):
    name_of_user = models.CharField()
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone_number_of_user = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    name_of_legal_entity = models.CharField()
    pan_number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    registered_office_address = models.CharField()
    store_name = models.CharField()
    location = models.CharField()
    store_address = models.CharField()
    store_contact_number = models.CharField()
    # store_timings = models.CharField() 


class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)  
    name_of_product = models.CharField()
    items_in_stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField()
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField()

class Category(models.Model):
    store_category = MultiSelectField(choices=MY_CHOICES) # grocery, meats, sports, foods, bags
```

**Process flow**

```
Choose a preferred store from the ones that deliver to you
Checkout the cart with everything you need
This app will then pick up the items from the shop and deliver to you
```

I tried to design it in django for my practice but i am confuse with how i can show store category and product relation like in gorfers.com and also with the location and store timing.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
class Store(models.Model):
    name_of_user = models.CharField()
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone_number_of_user = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    name_of_legal_entity = models.CharField()
    pan_number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    registered_office_address = models.CharField()
    store_name = models.CharField()
    # For location - using latitude and longitude
    store_long = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=8, null=True)
    store_lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=8, null=True)
    # End location
    store_address = models.CharField()
    store_contact_number = models.CharField()
    store_start_time = models.DateTimeField()  # start of when a store is closed
    store_end_time = models.DateTimeField()  # ending of when a store is closed


class Category(models.Model):    
    GROCERY = 0
    MEATS = 1
    SPORTS = 2
    FOODS = 3
    BAGS = 4

    STORE_CATEGORIES= (
        (GROCERY, _('Grocery')),
        (MEATS, _('Meats')),
        (SPORTS, _('Sports')),
        (FOODS, _('Foods')),
        (BAGS, _('Bags')),
    )
    store_category = models.IntegerField(
        choices=STORE_CATEGORIES, default=GROCERY)
```

Comment: one user can have multiple store with different category and single category can have multiple products.For example I can have two store and one store is of grocery and other is of sports. The grocery store can have multiple products and store based on sports category can have multiple products.

Comment: yes like @Tushant said. I want the model exactly like that. I have updated my qestion.